# How to get rid of : class type required but T found

Tags: scala

How to solve this compilation error :

```
trait Container {
  def getInts() : Seq[Int]
  def getStrings() : Seq[String]

  def put[T](t: T)
  def get[T] : Seq[T]
}

class MutableContainer extends Container {
  val entities = new mutable.HashMap[Class[_], mutable.Set[Any]]() with mutable.MultiMap[Class[_], Any]

  override def getStrings(): Seq[String] = entities.get(classOf[String]).map(_.toSeq).getOrElse(Seq.empty).asInstanceOf[Seq[String]] //strings
  override def getInts(): Seq[Int] = entities.get(classOf[Int]).map(_.toSeq).getOrElse(Seq.empty).asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]

  override def get[T]: Seq[T] = entities.get(classOf[T]).map(_.toSeq).getOrElse(Seq.empty).asInstanceOf[Seq[T]]
  override def put[T](t: T): Unit = entities.addBinding(t.getClass, t)
}
```

Here is the error :

```
[error] Container.scala:23: class type required but T found
[error]       override def get[T]: Seq[T] = entities.get(classOf[T]).map(_.toSeq).getOrElse(Seq.empty).asInstanceOf[Seq[T]]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`T` is not a class type, but a type parameter. Request a `ClassTag`:

```
import scala.reflect._

override def get[T](implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): Seq[T] =
  entities.get(ct.runtimeClass)
          .map(_.toSeq)
          .getOrElse(Seq.empty)
          .asInstanceOf[Seq[T]]
```

But this brings another problem; this is not an override!

So you have to modify the base class to declare `get` as follows:

```
def get[T: ClassTag]: Seq[T]
```

Comment: no other way to tell the compiler a type parameter is necessarily a class type? [I even tried a type parameter T <: SomeClass in my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797731/passing-a-type-parameter-for-instantiation), and the type bound didn't convince the compiler this is a type :(

Answer (score 3):

A solution without reflection

```
trait Container {
  def getInts() : Seq[Int]
  def getStrings() : Seq[String]
  def put[T](clazz: Class[T],t :T)
  def get[T](clazz: Class[T]) : Seq[T]
}

class MutableContainer extends Container {
  val entities = new mutable.HashMap[Class[_], mutable.Set[Any]]() with mutable.MultiMap[Class[_],Any]
  override def getStrings(): Seq[String] = entities.get(classOf[String]).map(_.toSeq).getOrElse(Seq.empty).asInstanceOf[Seq[String]] //strings
  override def getInts(): Seq[Int] = entities.get(classOf[Int]).map(_.toSeq).getOrElse(Seq.empty).asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]
  override def get[T](clazz: Class[T]): Seq[T] = entities.get(clazz).map(_.toSeq).getOrElse(Seq.empty).asInstanceOf[Seq[T]]
  override def put[T](clazz: Class[T],t :T): Unit = entities.addBinding(clazz, t)
}
```

Comment: That's a less fluent API. Caller code don't want to deal with that stuff.