# Passing a type parameter for instantiation

Tags: scala

Why wouldn't the scala compiler dig this:

```
class Clazz

class Foo[C <: Clazz] {
  val foo = new C  
}

class type required but C found
[error]   val a = new C
[error]               ^
```

Related question - [How to get rid of : class type required but T found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567370/how-to-get-rid-of-class-type-required-but-t-found)

Comment: Could you make sure to update your example so the names match and make sense?

Comment: Done, apologies. We can both remove our comment now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic generic problem that also happens in Java - you cannot create an instance of a generic type variable. What you can do in Scala to fix this, however, is to introduce a type evidence to your type parameter that captures the runtime type:

```
class Foo[C <: Clazz](implicit ct: ClassTag[C]) {
    val foo = ct.runtimeClass.newInstance
}
```

Note that this only works if the class has a constructor without any arguments. Since the parameter is implicit, you don't need to pass it when calling the Foo constructor:

```
Foo[Clazz]()
```

Comment: isn't the case of a constructor without any arguments a rather limited subset to enjoy this solution though?

Comment: Unless you pass the parameters, I don't see how anything else could work. If you want to have more options, I would suggest using the factory solution or passing the value of the field directly.

Comment: After implementing both ways, it is arguably hard to decide which is actually more ugly. The value is typed by the compiler as `Any` rather than as `C`, inevitably so because the class is determined by the runtime method `runtimeClass`. Whereas in my suggested answer there is an opposite yet very similar distortion that can't be avoided. I find it hard to even call this type safe. How sad.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this scheme, couldn't simplify it through a companion object thought.

```
class Clazz
class ClazzFactory {
  def apply = new Clazz
}

class Foo(factory: ClazzFactory) {
  val foo: Clazz = factory.apply
}
```

It's very annoying that ClazzFactory can't be an object rather than a class though. A simplified version:

```
class Clazz {
  def apply() = new Clazz
}

class Foo(factory: Clazz) {
  val foo: Clazz = factory.apply
}
```

This requires the caller to use the new keyword in order to provide the factory argument, which is already a minor enough annoyance relative to the initial problem. But, scala could have made this scenario all more elegant; I had to fallback here to passing a parameter of the type I wish to instantiate, plus the `new` keyword. Maybe there's a better way.

(motivation was to instantiate that type many times within the real `Foo`, that's why this is at all a solution; otherwise my pattern above is just redundantly meaningless).